# Lazy insertion vs. manual insertion

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I saw that EntityFramework was able to create and update nested objects automatically.
For example, if you take an Account, that is linked to an Address with a foreign key, if you create an account that has its Address navigation property filled, the Address will automatically updated. Also, if you update that Account and its Address navigation property is filled with data, it will automatically update them too.

But we know that lazy things are not that good (especially with Lazy Loading), but I never saw anyone talking about that one.

So should you take each entity as object in your services, and insert them manually so you can gather their ID and fill your objects as the process run, or should you fill one big object, give it to EF Core, and let him do the rest ?

Comment: "But we know that lazy things are not that good (especially with Lazy Loading), but I never saw anyone talking about that one." What do you mean here? Why are lazy things "not so good"? There are situations, where lazy loading might be pretty good performance-wise.

Comment: Because Lazy Loading is known for causing performance issues, for causing loop referencing errors, and (at least in the industry I am working) we would rather specify which navigation properties we need in our objects, so we just take what we need and nothing more

Comment: If you can't (or don't want to) use lazy loading, than don't do. Functions exist for a specific purpose. So they aren't inherently good or bad. They might simply not fit your needs. So when you notices problems with the lazy-loading and can achieve your needs by other means, feel free to not use lazy-loading at all. No-one forces you to do so.

Comment: If one should create a service for each entity depends on the use case. Propably that is not useful for the application. If you need 5 different entities for example that would be a horrible move. But if you need only one it can make sence.

Comment: @Baptiste there's no such thing as "lazy" or "manual" insertion. Please fix the title to reflect the actual question. As for `causing performance issues`, that's the case with all things that are used improperly. That includes all related objects when you only need one, which mean *eager* loading can be bad too

Comment: @Baptiste the entire question is based on an incorrect mental model. ORMs like EF Core or NHibernate try to give the impression of working with in-memory objects instead of tables and rows. When the time comes, they persist *all* pending changes to the objects they track at once, in a single database transaction. That's not visible to the programmer, it all happens inside the `SaveChanges` method. The term "lazy" or "manual" has no meaning at all in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: It depends.

If you are building a web application and expecting to load a top level entity and it's relations, send it to the view as a Model, then expect to accept that back in a Form POST then you can absolutely expect to encounter a lot of pain with EF, especially on the trip back to the server.

If you have an operation where you want to load a reasonably complete picture of an entity and it's related data, run logic based on the various state combinations and desired actions on those entities, make modifications, then call `SaveChanges()`, EF is perfectly suited to operations like this since you would want those changes all committed or rolled back together.

For web applications I generally advise designing the applications to work in incremental operations. If it isn't practical to save those changes to the database individually then I will use a temporary state either in Session or DB to persist the changes individually, then when the user selects to commit those changes, load the entity graph, validate the concurrency version marker, apply the changes, and save the entity graph.

The biggest mistake I see developers do that get them in trouble is using entities as DTOs in web applications or view models in web/WPF. This isn't what they are suited to do, and in all but the simplest examples (and there are a lot of official examples doing just this) run into any number of problems ranging from lazy loading performance issues, cyclic references and serialization, unexplained null data, stale data overwrites, instance already tracked exceptions, etc.